# C# Dice application, with die images

Tags: c#

The question: Create an application that simulates rolling a pair of dice. When the user clicks a button, the application should generate two random numbers, each in the range of 1 through 6, to represent the value of the dice. Use PictureBox controls to display the dice.

I currently have 6 picture boxes with the picture boxes named "dice1PictureBox", "dice2PictureBox" etc, up to 6.

Here is the code I have written so far. I am completely lost at this point. I am also very new at programming, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    private void rollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int diceOne;
        int diceTwo;

        Random rand = new Random();

        diceOne = rand.Next(3);

        if (diceOne == 0)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }
        else (diceOne == 1)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }
         else (diceOne == 2)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }

        diceTwo = rand.Next(4) + 6;

        if (diceOne == 3)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }
        else (diceOne == 4)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }
         else (diceOne == 5)
        {
            diceOne.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For reference, the problem says *each* die has a value from 1 to 6.  Meaning, you're going to have a total of 12 `if`s if you go this route.  Also, this code isn't going to compile, as `int`s don't have a `Visible` property.

Comment: You have the same thing happening regardless of which "diceOne == x" case is True.  You'll need to set a different image to become visible each time, or you'll be displaying diceOne no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the general idea here.  I'm not going to even bother with how you're doing things right now, cause it's not going to do what you want.  Period.

All you need is *two* PictureBoxes, one for each die.  You then have 6 images, one for each possible value.  I'd suggest keeping the images in an array or perhaps an ImageList (either way, let's call it `images`); it will make things much simpler.

When you roll, for each die, you'll say something like `roll = rand.Next(6);`. `roll` will then correspond to the index of the image in the array.  You set the `Image` of the corresponding PictureBox to `images[roll]` (or `images.Images[roll]` if you're using an ImageList).  No need to mess with `Visible`; the two PictureBoxes will always be visible.

Just be aware that when you consider the actual value of `roll`, it will be from 0 to 5.  Add 1 to get the value people expect to see.

Comment: Thanks cHao, I will definitely try an array.

Comment: So something like this roll [5] = dice1PictureBox1, dice2PictureBox1,dice3PictureBox1, dice4PictureBox1, dice5PictureBox1,dice6PictureBox1. Ill be honest im not very good with arrays.

Comment: What would I declare "roll" as?

Comment: `roll` is an int, of course -- that's what you get back from `rand.Next`, and the type you use for array indexes.  And you don't really want a dozen PictureBoxes; you want *two* PictureBoxes and an array of images.  I mean, if your teacher really really really *wants* you to use a dozen, go for it...but it's the wrong way to go about it, and no teacher that's worth a damn will tell you to do it that way.

Comment: How do I add more than one image to a picturebox?

Comment: You don't.  You set the `Image` property of the PictureBox to the image corresponding to the dice roll.  Only one image is ever in the PictureBox at a time.

Comment: Im still lost. I tried this but its still giving errors.         const int ROLL = 5;
 
                 images [ROLL] = rand.Next(6);
                 images [0] = pictureBox1;...etc...                          I don't know what you mean, or how to set the image property of the PictureBox to the image. Can you give me some staring code/sample code so I can get an example of what you mean please?

Comment: @EASTON: You understand what setting properties means?  `pictureBox1.Image = images[roll];`  You really need to understand the difference between the roll (the random number), the image corresponding to that roll, and the PictureBox where the image will show up.  The PictureBox is not the image -- it just displays one -- and its contents can be changed pretty much at will by setting `pictureBox1.Image` to a different image.

Comment: ok, so now since I have the images in my Resources folder how do I import those when the array needs them? For example when its pictureBox1.Image = images [0], how do I make it that it displays die with the # 1??

Comment: If you added the resource to the app via the Properties page, the image is accessible as `Properties.Resources.WhateverYouCalledTheImage`. In order to do the array thing, you'll at some point need to create the array. Whether you do it when you declare it, or in the constructor, or in Form_Load, you'll need to have something like `images = new Image[] { Properties.Resources.DiceImage1, Properties.Resources.DiceImage2, ... };`. If you added the images some other way (like just sticking them in the Resources folder), i'm not sure how you'd access them. Adding them via the UI makes stuff simpler.

Comment: You could also just add an ImageList to the form, and use that instead of an array, and add the images in it.  That deals well with external resources, from what i've seen. In which case, you don't need an array, and you can say `pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[roll];`.

Comment: ok coo, so I got that, and the images in the resources. What do I declare images as? I tried Image images; but then I get an error at new Image[].

Comment: Array types have to be declared with the brackets.  So you'd have `Image[] images`.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers without completely telling you how to code it, because this seems like a homework assignment.

- [MSDN: if-else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) - you aren't constructing your if-else statements correctly.  Specifically, you can't use if/else/else.
- [MSDN: Random.Next(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx) - your first dice will always return a value of 3 or less.  Your second dice will always return a value of 6 or higher (you're adding 6 to a value of 0-4).  These do not meet the requirements you give.
- You are setting a `Visible` property on `int`s.  It seems like you are confusing the integers that represent the value of the die with the images.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I was looking at the text book, and the way it was written, seemed like I was doing it correctly. The links proved otherwise.